# XML order of duplicate element matters

Tags: xml, xsd

I've not managed to find an answer to this exact question and its bugging me.

I need to create an XML Schema where the order of duplicate elements matter. Example:

```
<article>
    <line>This article was</line>
    <line>written by</line>
</article>
```

I know the above example is rather contrived, but it illustrates my case. I have to deserialize a sequence of commands where the execution order matters. The only way I can see of achieving this is to add an `order="[integer]"` attribute to each child element (the `<line>` tags in the above example). That seems a bit heavy handed though, especially as the XML documents are going to be typed by hand. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Too much for XSD, just use XPath to query the document and populate your object properties.  Use application logic (not XSD), to verify order.

Comment: I don't really want to rely just on XML parser to ensure order is maintained when parsing. I on't think that's very safe. If there is no better solution, I'll use the `order` attribute as stated in the question

Comment: Huh? Order IS ALWAYS maintained during parsing, and ALL parsers retain it. It is essential part of XML data model. It may be that other libs on top may not care, but parsers never change the order, nor basic data models like DOM.

Comment: @StaxMan Ok. Thanks for the reply. Maybe I'm not understanding this, but this article section: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-eleord/index.html#N1009E appears to disagree with you!

Comment: Interesting article you found there. XML Schema is notoriously limited when it comes to unordered content, so it's pretty much the opposite of what you're afraid of.

Comment: @Clivest I don't know where the author gets his idea, but it certainly is a rather un-orthodox interpretation; especially since XML 1.0 DTD specification obviously defines ordered sequences of elements which are separate from unordered attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XML spec is very patchy in the reporting requirements it places on an XML parser. For example, it says that the parser has to report whitespace, but doesn't say it has to report other character content. But in practice, you can rely on XML parsers reporting character content, and keeping characters in the right order, and in the same way you can rely on elements being reported in the right order. The only reason the spec doesn't mandate this is that the authors thought it was too obvious to need saying. Your fears are completely unfounded.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Michael.  My team has been developing XML applications for the past 10 years (MSXML, .NET System.Xml), and have never run into problems with these parsers re-interpreting document order.